# I have issue with Twilio SDK Video call Remote view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

I am implementing the **Twilio SDK** for video calling functionality in my application but the remote view is not showing if the participant is connected with the room. When I connected with participant `TVIParticipantDelegate` method call and I add renderer video track to remote view.

Answer (score 2):

I added remoteview in dispatch main queue it works for me.

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [videoTrack addRenderer:self.remoteView];
    });
```

Comment: Yes, above code also worked for me, please make sure self.remoteView is connected with xib view.